# Change image and description according to the selected image

Tags: javascript, php, html, css, wordpress

Someone asked me to recreate this kind of thing, in the "Nos Service" part of this website: http://www.ohmygoodnesscafe.fr/, there's a gallery of four images. Under the gallery there's the selected image with text. When you click on a different picture, the content is changed accordingly, with the selected image and its description.
How can I achieve the same thing? Is there a plugin for this?

Answer (score 0):

```js
$('#tabs').on('click','li',function(e){

var tab = $(this).data('tab');

$('.pane.' + tab).addClass('active').siblings('.pane.active').removeClass('active');

});
```

```css
.pane {
display:none; padding:20px;
}
.pane.active {
display:block;
}
#tabs {
display:table; margin:0; padding:0;
}
#tabs li {
display:table-cell; background:blue; color:white; padding:10px; cursor:pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<ul id="tabs">
<li data-tab="one">One</li>
<li data-tab="two">Two</li>
<li data-tab="three">Three</li>
<li data-tab="four">Four</li>
</ul>

<div class="pane one active">
One data
</div>
<div class="pane two">
Two data
</div>
<div class="pane three">
Three data
</div>
<div class="pane four">
Four data
</div>
```